# How do i enter an arbitrary number into a field using pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Im trying to make `pyautogui` type in the variable, which is a number that keeps changing.

I tried `Typewrite()` and `keyDown()`.

This is the code:

```
pyautogui.keyDown("enter")
pyautogui.keyDown(count)
count += scale
```

I hoped that it would put in the variable and click enter. The enter part works btw. It didn't paste the variable as i hoped.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please complete your [tour] and see [ask].  For starter, it would be to your benefit to produce a [MCVE] that replicates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pyautogui.keyDown("enter")
pyautogui.keyDown(str(count))
count += scale'
```

If `count` is an integer, you first need to convert it to a string `str()`.

If you need to enter a number above `9`, you will need to do this:

```
for c in str(count):
    pyautogui.keyDown(c)
```

Because there's no `"10"` or above key on your keyboard.  `"1"` and `"0"` will need to be pressed individually.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Note if `count` goes above `9` it would not work because there's no key `"10"` on your keyboard.

Comment: You may also want to look at typewrite instead
`pyautogui.typewrite(str(count), interval=secs_between_keys)`
useful for entering text